# DBT permanent snapshot tables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

How to create DBT snapshot tables as permanent instead of transient in Snowflake environment?

Snapshot is a table materialization and it generates transient tables in Snowflake by default.
I tried `transient` flag, but it does not work with snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

- Project level on `dbt_project.yml`:

```
models:
  +transient: false
  my_project:
```

- Specific model, on its config:

```
{{ config(materialized='table', transient=false) }}

select * from ...
```

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/snowflake-configs#transient-tables

Comment: OP asks about snapshots. I don't think that setting transient under models works for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this for individual snapshots via the config block:

```
{% snapshot my_snapshot %}

    {{
        config(
            target_schema='snapshots',
            strategy='check',
            unique_key='id',
            check_cols=[col_1'],
            transient=false
        )
    }}
    
    select * from {{ source('my_source', 'my_table') }}
    
{% endsnapshot %}
```

I believe dbt [now supports doing this](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/1613) in dbt_project.yml in a snapshot section

```
snapshots:
  transient: false
```